# XPath to select all nodes between two text markers in OOXML?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri, openxml

I have a big XML file (from Microsoft Word) that contains tables, paragraphs, etc. I'm trying to grab all of the XML between two elements. For example, I want to grab all of the XML between these two

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00C82C88" w:rsidRDefault="00265695">
  <w:r>
    <w:t>#StartHere#</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
  a whole bunch of XML
<w:p w:rsidR="00C82C88" w:rsidRDefault="00265695" w:rsidP="00265695">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Caption"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">Figure </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00F044F8">
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00F044F8">
    <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> SEQ Figure \* ARABIC </w:instrText>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00F044F8">
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>1</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00F044F8">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>: #StopHere#</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

How can I have Nokogiri to grab me all of the XML between #StartHere# and #StopHere#, including those elements that this text is wrapped in? I'd like to call something like `extracted_data = document[from..stop]` somehow.

I can find those points in the document by looking for:

```
start = doc.at_xpath("//w:p[.//w:t[contains(., '#StartHere#')]]")
stop = doc.at_xpath("//w:p[.//w:t[contains(., '#StopHere#')]]")
```

but need to figure out how I can say document[start..stop] to grab everything (including those) and between it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XPath**,

```
//node()[    preceding::w:p[w:r/w:t[.='#StartHere#']] 
         and following::w:p[w:r/w:t[.=': #StopHere#']]]
```

will select all nodes between the two paragraphs that contain your marker text.

**In Nokogiri**: `doc.xpath("`*insert above XPath here*`")`

Comment: Thank you very much! Was looking for exactly this.

Comment: Hmm, how do I actually include this in my code? Would it be something along the lines of doc.xpath(//node()[preceding::w:p[w:r/w:t[.='#StartHere#']] and following::w:p[w:r/w:t[.=': #StopHere#']]])?

Comment: Answer updated to show Nokogiri XPath invokation.   (Surround by double quotes (`" "`).)